# jQuery select menu data attributes and set background image URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the feeling I'm going around this totally the wrong way; here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qhuprcLz/

What I'm trying to do is whenever I hover a main menu option, I want to grab the data-type set on that menu and set class on the main and then when I hover on the sub menu any of the menu items to get the data-background attr and set the background image on the container.

I loaded the site and menu into the jsfiddle so you can get a better understanding of what I mean.

JS:

```
// tablet and desktop only
    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 960px)').matches) {  

        // menu background
        $('.menu-menu ul li.cm-menu-item-responsive').on("mouseover", function () {
            var menuType = $(this).attr("data-type");
            var menuBackground = $(menuType + " .ty-menu__submenu-list li").attr("data-background");

            console.log("menu type:"+menuType);
            console.log("menu background:"+menuBackground);

            $(this).find("div.ty-menu__submenu").addClass(menuType);
            $(this).find("div.ty-menu__submenu").css('background-image', 'url(menu-' + menuBackground + '.png)');
        });

    }
```

Comment: One thing I can teach you is to use the jquery .data() function instead of using `.attr('data-background')` you can get the same info using `.data('background')`

Comment: @Peter using `.attr('data-...')` seems to be more reliable in my experience, as, for example, my older android native browser will fail with `.data(...)`, but succeed with the `.attr('data-...')`

Comment: Noted guys, thanks however what ive done so far does not seem to work with setting the background image for the hovered element. Its setting but undefined on the background.

Comment: If i use var menuBackground = $(".ty-menu__submenu-list li").attr("data-background"); it sets the background however does not change it when you hover other sub items... any ideas?

Comment: I noticed that the class "ty-menu__submenu-list" only exists on the very last level (i.e. home > interior > gold > butterfly). all others have different (and very complicated) classes.
And I still don't quite know what it is exactly you want to achieve, and in which cases... Could you give us an example? And maybe tidy up the JSFiddle a bit? there is SO much to look at right now.
There are several sub-menus. As I understand it, you want to change the parent's background according to a sub-menu. But you run this when ever a parent is hovered, so: which child should the background come from?

Comment: Ive managed to work something out its ok, however just stuck removing previous classes being set. thinking might removeClass using some form of wildcard as all classes im settings end in bean-bags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution i came up with is as follows:

```
// menu background
        $('.menu-menu ul li.cm-menu-item-responsive').on("mouseover", function () {
            var menuType = $(this).attr("data-type");
            $(this).find("div.ty-menu__submenu").addClass(menuType);

        });
        $('.ty-menu__submenu-list li').on("mouseover", function () {
            var menuBackground = $(this).attr("data-background");
            //console.log(menuBackground);
            $("div.ty-menu__submenu.ty-menu__submenu-to-right").addClass(menuBackground);
        });
```